# ¿Porque no puedo acceder a una ruta excluida en Spring Security?

Tags: spring, http, jwt, spring-security, auth

Primero agradecer a quienes se tomen el tiempo de leer esta pregunta.

Para dar más contexto, estoy tratando de hacer una API REST con Spring Boot en Java, e utilizar Spring Security con JWT para la authorización de los recursos. Además, estoy utilizando PostgreSQL y Spring JPA para la persistencia de datos.

Comenzaré mostrando el dominio, que en este caso es una clase Usuario

```
package com.finapp.domain.entities;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import com.finapp.domain.valueobjects.Email;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Email email;
    private String password;
    private Role role;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Y una clase Role

```
package com.finapp.domain.entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Cabe destacar que estoy utilizando una arquitectura limpia, por lo cual, las entidades que interactuan con JPA están en la capa de infrasetructura y no en el dominio. Por lo cual, el código de las clases JPA son las siguientes:

Clase UserEntity

```
package com.finapp.infrastructure.persistence.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private RoleEntity role;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

Clase RoleEntity

```
package com.finapp.infrastructure.persistence.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class RoleEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserEntity> users;
}
```

Estoy utilizando patrón CRQS, pero no mostraré el código, ya que, el método principal es registrar un usuario.

Luego para implementar JWT tengo las siguientes clases:

Clase JwtService :

```
package com.finapp.infrastructure.config;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Service
public class JwtService {

    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "SHA256";

    public String extractUsername(String jwt) {
        return extractClaim(jwt, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String jwt, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(jwt);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails
    ) {
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String jwt, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(jwt);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(jwt);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String jwt) {
        return extractExpiration(jwt).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String jwt) {
        return extractClaim(jwt, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String jwt) {
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

Luego tengo un filtro clase AuthenticationFilter

```
package com.finapp.infrastructure.config;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource()
                                .buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

La configuración de Spring Security :

Clase SecurityConfiguration:

```
package com.finapp.infrastructure.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/authentication/register").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Y para terminar la Clase ApplicationConfiguration:

```
package com.finapp.infrastructure.config;

import com.finapp.domain.repositories.IUserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private final IUserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

Ya por ultimo, tengo el controlador con la ruta que está excluida:

```
package com.finapp.presentation.controllers.commands;


import com.finapp.infrastructure.dto.auth.AuthenticationResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import com.finapp.application.commands.auth.RegisterCommand;
import com.finapp.application.commands.auth.RegisterCommandHandler;

@Repository
@RequestMapping("/api/authentication")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegisterCommandController {

    private final RegisterCommandHandler commandHandler;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody RegisterCommand command) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(commandHandler.handle(command));
    }

}
```

Pero cuando realizo la solicitud, aun así paso por el filtro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado todo pero no puedo comprender porque no me está excluyendo la ruta, si esta configurada en el filtro.